# PEM formatted SSH cert with RFC 4716 format keys

Tags: openssh, ssh-keys

I am trying to get a ssh cert for sftp setup with 3rd party vendor in pem format and should be SSH2, using RSA algo with the Key lengths of 2048.

Do the below steps make some sense (Please correct me if I am wrong)

1. First, I need to create a key pair. `ssh-keygen -f ssh_host_rsa_key -N '' -b 2048 -t rsa`
2. Convert them to ssh2/RFC4716 format. `ssh-keygen -ef ssh_host_rsa_key -mRFC4716(private key)`
3. Crate a CA key pair and try to sign the pub key with CA private key and derive the SSH cert.
4. Once we have the SSH cert, convert it into PEM format.

I followed the below process but struck here.

1. First, created a key pair with 2048 length (command: `ssh-keygen -f ssh_host_rsa_key -N ‘’ -b 2048 -t rsa`) Private key starts with (BEGIN OPENSSH PRIVATE KEY) Public key starts with (ssh-rsa)
2. Converted the private key( I believe private key will contain keypair(pri key+ pub key_) to SSH2/RFC4716 format and named the new file ssh_host_rsa_key_4716) Command: ssh-keygen -ef ssh_host_rsa_key -mRFC4716 > ssh_host_rsa_key_4716)

The private key changed to SSH2 format but public key is still (starts with ssh-rsa). So I manually converted the public key to ssh2 format.

However, when I created pair of CA keys and tried to sign the public key with CA private key, it took the original pub key with(ssh-rsa format) but not the converted ssh2 format pub key.

Can you please give your input or any guidance?

I tried different key combinations but for some reason I am missing some basic things. Trying to generate an ssh cert for SFTP setup but stuck on the way.

Comment: Are you sure the vendor supports verifying OpenSSH-format certificates? If they require a pubkey in RFC4716 format, they most likely support only raw pubkeys. (And, why does the _private_ key need to be in a specific format? The server doesn't know or care what format the privkey is in.)

Comment: thanks for the reponse @user 1686. I am not sure whey they need this format, I will check with them but is this scenario possible by any chance and work  successfully ?

Comment: It's technically possible (all SSH pubkey formats can hold any key type, you might just need to sign it first and convert after), but practically unlikely.

Comment: are the below steps look ok to get this done?
1.First, I need to create a key pair. ( ssh-keygen -f ssh_host_rsa_key -N '' -b 2048 -t rsa) 
2.Convert them to ssh2/RFC4716 format. (ssh-keygen -ef ssh_host_rsa_key -mRFC4716(private key) 
3.Crate a CA key pair and try to sign the pub key with CA private key and get the SSH cert. 
4. Once we have the SSH cert, convert it into PEM format.

Comment: I don't really understand why the CA is involved here at all. What purpose does signing the user pubkey serve? It would make sense if you were using an existing, established internal CA to sign it, but you're creating a brand new CA – which the server doesn't know about – do you really *need* it at all?

Comment: Thanks. Its a small setup. sorry i just came to know,  and they are ok with self-signed ssh Certificate as well. May be its my misake to consider creating CA keys. Seems like they are ok with open ssh/ssl. It just needs to be pem formatted cert and should be SSH2, either the RSA or DSA public key encryption algorithms can be used. Key lengths of 1024 (default) or 2048 are supported.

Comment: Can you please give your inputs on creating self signed ssh cert with required format above. how can we get the self signed cert?

Comment: There's no such thing as "self-signed certs" in SSH – in their place, you would use raw public keys without *any* CA-signing. That is, literally just the .pub file that a regular ssh-keygen gives you. (TLS only has self-signed certs because it started off with X.509 format certs, whereas SSH started off without any CAs at all.) PEM files don't need to be certs, they can also contain raw public keys (these days usually in PKCS#8 format).

Comment: Thanks, in a way  your explanation  helped me to resolve this. Thanks this can be closed.

Answer (score 0):

Issue is resolved using public/private key authentication. This can be closed. Thanks **user1686**

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).